# insert into instance in a repeat

Tags: orbeon

my **situation** is the following:

1. I have a nodeset, through which I iterate and populate a table with some of the data
2. One of the fields, I do want to sum up

**The problem:**
Unfortunately I cannot use the sum method for the calculation as the nodeset is custom function that accesses data from other forms. And that seems to mess up things.

**My idea of a solution:**
I thought, I could create an instance and in each iteration add the value to it. Then I simply could access that data and do whatever calculation required. But I cannot get the xforms:insert to work.

A simplified version looks like this:

```
            <xforms:repeat nodeset="(xxforms:si-source-forms('other_form'))">
              <!-- table here -->
              <xforms:insert
                 nodeset="instance('fr-form-instance')//positionen/position"
                 origin="instance('neue-position')"/>
            </xforms:repeat>
```

The 'neue-position' instance contains bindings to the values in the source form:

```
  <xforms:bind id="neue-position-binds" nodeset="instance('neue-position')">
    <xforms:bind id="neue-position-bind" nodeset="position">
      <xforms:bind id="neue-position-summe-bind" nodeset="summe" name="summe" type="xforms:string" required="true" xxforms:default="xxforms:si-source-forms('other_form')//gesamtbetrag_ausgabe" />
    </xforms:bind>
  </xforms:bind>
```

It does not work as expected though, so obviously something is wrong. I'd appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About your first code snippet:**

Your `<xforms:insert>` won't have any effet. You're in the view, and an action only runs if it is attached to an event listener. Without an `ev:listener` on the `<xforms:insert>` (or on an action around that insert), it just won't run.

**About doing a sum over nodes not in an instance:**

Assuming there is just one "sum" over the data returns by your custom function, you could write code along those lines:

1. Store the sequence of nodes returned by the function in an variable `<xf:var name="others" ref="xxforms:si-source-forms('other_form')"/>`
2. Use that variable in the repeat: `<xf:repeat ref="$others">` (BTW, now XForms is standardizing the use of `ref` everywhere, in place of `nodeset`).
3. Do your calculation: `<xf:var name="my-sum" ref="sum($others/path/to/values)"/>`.
4. Finally, I imagine that you want to do something with `$my-sum`, maybe show it with an `<xf:output>`.

Comment: Thanks for that, it got me up and running the right direction.